# Checking some columns for specific values before insert/update using a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

I have a database FOO with several columns, among those I have one column "Url". I need to write a trigger before insert/update that will check the Url columns whether the newer value matches any existing values, i.e. "hello" except some predefined value. That means if "hello" is inserted or updated multiple times no error will happen otherwise it will check for duplicity. And if it finds some aborts the insertion update. This will also return some code so that my script calling for the insertion/update will know a failure has occurred. I know there might be other workarounds but I will need to have it this way. I am pretty new to SQL.

```
Foo {
    Url
}
```

Here is the algorithm

```
Before update insert
if new value of Url is not "hello1" o "hello 2" 
    check if new value of Url already exists in Foo.Url if so abort otherwise allow update/insert
     return something if aborted/success
```

Comment: What you are describing is EXACTLY what constraints are for. In this case a unique constraint. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, use the features of the tool you are using.

Comment: I know but the situation kindof tricky. We need to work on a table with legacy data and cannot add a new constraint. The Url column is nullable and some of the URLs will have multiple values inside the database. We need to make sure newer inserts updates excluding those predefined Urls are not duplcate.

Comment: So you are ok with crappy data in the database as long as it isn't new crappy data? That doesn't sound like a good idea at all.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.. you'll need to index your table..

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT URL FROM  Foo.Url)
      BEGIN 
       SELECT 'URL Exists Already'
      END
   ELSE 
     BEGIN 

      INSERT/UPDATE

     END
```

Answer (score 0):

A unique constraint wouldn't do what you want but you could create an instead of trigger with content something like as:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[Trig_Insert_XXX]
ON [dbo].[XXX]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO xxx ([url], field1, field2, fieldN)
  SELECT [url], field1, field2, fieldN
  FROM inserted i
  WHERE i.url = 'hello' OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM xxx t2 WHERE t2.url = i.url);
END;
```

Comment: This mostly works but if there is a duplicate it will just quietly not insert any duplicate rows. This would leave people scratching their head why the data isn't inserted.

Comment: @SeanLange, nope. You could return back information if you wanted to. From the definition however, there is no need to return info, they want 'hello' be inserted and rest not be duplicates (they would find the data there and no scratching is needed).

Comment: Well this silent changing things is why I strongly dislike instead of triggers. In this type of situation you issue an insert statement but there are no new rows in the table because the trigger made the decision to not insert the row. As a user that makes no sense. But in this case the OP stated they want something returned always. "return something if aborted/success"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for a `UNIQUE` constraint & a `CHECK` constraint as

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
  Url VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT UQ_Url UNIQUE(Url),
  CONSTRAINT CHK_Url CHECK (Url NOT IN ('hello1', 'hello2'))
);
```

[See how it's working online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=834164e0aa4a76ad20989278ae4b4c05).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer version you can use MERGE as well, the syntax is like the following :

```
MERGE [TableName] AS TARGET 
USING ( SELECT @UrlName ) AS SOURCE (UrlName) ON SOURCE.UrlName = TARGET.UrlName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ()
VALUES ();
```