# Trigger: Inserted table column value cannot be referenced inside condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have the following trigger:

```
    GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FooTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Foo]
FOR INSERT
AS 
DECLARE @Url nvarchar(MAX)
SELECT @Url  = ins.Url from INSERTED ins;

IF EXISTS (SELECT *  
           FROM [dbo].[Foo]  p   
           where p.Url =  @Url)  
BEGIN  
RAISERROR ( 'error %s' , 16, 1, @Url)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
RETURN   
END;
PRINT 'Executed Trigger Insert.'
GO
```

It works without an issue if I hardcode the condition like

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Foo] foo WHERE foo.Url = 'test.com')
```

But the original one does not work. It throws the message:

It looks like there is an error referencing the inserted table data using @Url inside the condition. But `RAISERROR ( @Url , 16, 1);` correctly printing the value, so I think inside the condition the referencing is somehow not permitted. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: As an aside, this `SELECT @Url  = ins.Url from INSERTED ins;` is broken, `INSERTED` is a table and can contain many rows. Any code must handle this situation.

Comment: And if you are trying to prevent duplicates why not use a unique constraint?

Comment: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Foo] foo WHERE foo.[Url] in (select [Url] from Inserted))` solves the first problem.

Comment: @DaleK It is treating it as a stored procedure and if I use  in  (select [Url] from Inserted) it always returns true for Exists check

Comment: When you asked what is happening. When I use foo.Url = Url it treats Url as stored procedure. And when I use IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Foo] foo WHERE foo.[Url] in (select [Url] from Inserted)) it always return true.

Comment: whatever I pass as Url to invoke the trigger by initiating an insert it throws the message
"Could not find stored procedure 'test.com'"

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) that started earlier today with the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286195/checking-some-columns-for-specific-values-before-insert-update-using-a-trigger). The OP wants to prevent new bad data from getting in but is ok with existing data that violates the data integrity rules. Hence the need to use a trigger instead of a constraint.

Comment: @DaleK
Edited my code

It is always returning true and the rollback happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you are trying to ensure that `url`s are unique, then use a unique constraint:

```
alter table foo add constraint unq_foo_url unique (url);
```

Second, NEVER assume that `inserted` has only one row.  This code:

```
SELECT @Url  = ins.Url from INSERTED ins;
```

is a bug waiting to happen.

EDIT:

You have a messy problem if you have a table that already violates the unique constraint.  You can fix this problem.  The issue with your code is that a `FOR INSERT` trigger is really an `AFTER INSERT` trigger -- the new data is already visible.

But, you can handle this.  Here is one way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[FooInsertTrigger]
ON [dbo].[Foo]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*)
        FROM inserted i JOIN
             [dbo].[Foo] f
             on i.url = f.url 
        GROUP BY i.url
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       ) > 1
    BEGIN  
        RAISERROR('Duplicate URL found' , 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
        RETURN   
    END;
    PRINT 'Executed Trigger Insert.'
END;
```

The maximum `count(*)` is greater than 1 in the following cases:

- `inserted.url` matches 1 row in `foo`.  This is the normal case.
- `inserted.url` matches multiple rows in `foo`.  This is caught.

This will also catch the case where there are multiples in `inserted`.

By making the code safe for multiple inserts, it is harder to pull out the offending URLs.  But the error is handled correctly.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=243d60954ce9a8c7bbe607df1f257be6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I cannot use a unique constraint that is the problem. It a legacy table with old urls that cannot be guaranteed to be unique.